# How can we attach a service account to cloud run service while deploying through github actions?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, github-actions, google-cloud-run, github-actions-workflows

I am trying to deploy a cloud run service using github workflow, this cloud run service performs some gcp actions for which I want to bind a service account to the cloud run service while deploying the same.

through gcloud cli we can achieve the same by using `--service-account <service-account>` option.

I want to achieve this using github actions as mentioned below:

```
      - name: Deploy to Cloud Run
        id: deploy
        uses: google-github-actions/deploy-cloudrun@v0
        with:
          service: ${{ env.SERVICE }}
          region: ${{ env.REGION }}
          # NOTE: If using a pre-built image, update the image name here
          image: gcr.io/${{ env.PROJECT_ID }}/${{ env.SERVICE }}:${{ github.sha }}
          flags: |
            --allow-unauthenticated
```

please let me know if there is any options,
I have explored this [link](https://github.com/google-github-actions/deploy-cloudrun) but I could not find any option for service-account

Comment: Under `flags`, add: `--service-account=<service-account-email-address>`

Comment: Post an answer after you verify my suggestion.

Comment: Sure @JohnHanley, currently I am waiting for IAM permissions from the IT team, but the configuration did not give any error other than IAM permissions, I'll update the answer once I verify the complete deployment

Comment: Any update for this? Does John Hanley answer your question?

Comment: Hie @Chanpols, Yes John's Answer works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the workflow yaml configuration we can define the service-account using flag as shown below:

```
- name: Deploy to Cloud Run
        id: deploy
        uses: google-github-actions/deploy-cloudrun@v0
        with:
          service: ${{ env.SERVICE }}
          region: ${{ env.REGION }}
          # NOTE: If using a pre-built image, update the image name here
          image: gcr.io/${{ env.PROJECT_ID }}/${{ env.SERVICE }}:${{ github.sha }}
          flags: |
            --allow-unauthenticated
            --service-account=<service-account-email>
```